# Sorting elements from a list of tuples into two separate lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

As the title says I'm in the process of sorting tagged elements into two lists.
My current code for this is:

```
lst = [("foo", "good"), ("bar", "bad")...("x", "n")]

def sort(items):
    good = []
    bad = []
    for i in range(len(items)):
        if items[i][1] == 'good':
            good += items[i][0]
        else:
            bad += items[i][0]
    return good, bad


alpha, beta = sort(lst)
```

My output is simply `f`. I've been trying to work this out for a while but the solution has been eluding me.
Any suggestions?

Thank you all.

Comment: `good.append(...` instead of `+=`

Comment: I fixed it almost as soon as I posted this question by changing `good += items[i][0]` to `good += [items[i][0]]`  but thank you for your response.

Comment: I very strongly advise **not** to name your function `sort`, because everyone reading your code using that function will assume that it performs a `sort` in the universal meaning of that word in computer science. I.e., that it does the same thing as builtin function `sorted` or as `list.sort`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the name just for this question, the name in the actual program is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve this in a cleaner way using `list comprenhension` to compute both lists:

```
def sort(items):
    good = [item[0] for item in items if item[1] == 'good']
    bad = [item[0] for item in items if item[1] == 'bad']

    return good, bad
```

If **performance** is not an issue this could be better due to it is a **declarative** approach instead of an **imperative** one so it could be easier to read, but takes into account that it iterates the list twice.

Hopes it helps you!

Comment: Won't this be slower as it goes through the list twice?

Comment: @Severin12121 I think that would depends on the size of the list because `list comprehension` usually are faster to regular `for-loops`. I have updated the answer to specify this matter and why this could be better in some cases (just for readability).

Comment: I think it would be both more readable and more efficient to iterate on the items directly rather than on the indices!

Comment: Yes, that's true! I'll edit the answer to change it!

Answer (score 3):

You can fix your code:

```
def sort(items):
    good = []
    bad = []
    for x, y in items:
        if y == 'good':
            good.append(x)
        else:
            bad.append(x)
    return good, bad
```

Note that `+=` corresponds to `list.extend` which adds iterables element-wise. For strings that means char by char.

Answer (score 2):

To create new lists with mapping or filtering, it's often shorter and easier to read to use **list comprehensions** rather than calling `.append` in a loop:

```py
data = [("foo", "good"), ("bar", "bad"), ("head", "good"), ("tails", "bad"), ("x", "n")]

good_lst = [x for x,quality in data if quality == 'good']
bad_lst = [x for x,quality in data if quality != 'good']

print(good_lst)
# ['foo', 'head']
print(bad_lst)
# ['bar', 'tails', 'x']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but you need to change one thing:

```
items[i][0] -> [items[i][0]]
```

When you want to use `+` you need to have values as list:

```
>>> [2,3] + [4]
[2,3,4]
```

Your code with one change:

```
lst = [("foo", "good"), ("bar", "bad"), ("head", "good"), ("tails", "bad")]

def sort(items):
    good = []
    bad = []
    for item in items:
        if item[1] == 'good':
            good += [item[0]]
        else:
            bad += [item[0]]
    return good, bad


alpha, beta = sort(lst)
print (alpha, beta)
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'head'] ['bar', 'tails']
```

Answer (score 0):

`+=` is used when you try to add `LHS` to `RHS` with same datatype. When you do `good += items[i][0]` it's like adding `foo` as a list (`['f', 'o', 'o']`) to the list `good`. That's the reason you see the behavior. Hence use `list.append()` to add element to a list.
Try out this:

```
lst = [("foo", "good"), ("bar", "bad"), ("head", "good"), ("tails", "bad")]

def sort(items):
    good = []
    bad = []
    for item in items:
        #print (item, type(item))
        if item[1] == 'good':
            good.append(item[0])
        else:
            bad.append(item[0])
    return good, bad


alpha, beta = sort(lst)
print (alpha, beta)
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'head'] ['bar', 'tails']
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed `good += items[i][0]` to `good.append(i[0])`

```
lst = [("foo", "good"),("bar", "bad"),("x", "n")]

def sort(items):
    good = []
    bad = []
    for i in items:
        if i[1] == 'good':
            good.append(i[0])
        else:
            bad.append(i[0])
    return good, bad


alpha, beta = sort(lst)
print(alpha)
print(beta)
```

Output:

```
['foo']
['bar', 'x']
```